# How to get the get method parameters in jsp?

Tags: html, jsp

After getting a input from the first page, I passed it in to the url using get method. In the next page I want to process it using jsp, but how do I get that parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it off of the request object.

```
request.getParameter("<param name>");
```